# using numba to speedup solve_ivp

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-methods, numba, pde

I am using the method of lines with 'solve_ivp` to solve a nonlinear [PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_equation):

```
@njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy",cache=True)
def thinFilmEq(t,h,dx,Ma,phiFun,tempFun):
    phi = phiFun(h)
    temperature = tempFun(h)
    hxx = (np.roll(h,1) - 2*h + np.roll(h,-1))/dx**2  # use np.roll as I'm implementing periodic BC
    p = phi - hxx
    px = (np.roll(p,-1) - np.roll(p,1))/(2*dx)
    Tx = (np.roll(temperature,-1) - np.roll(temperature,1))/(2*dx)

    flux = h**3*px/3 + Ma*h**2*Tx/2
    dhdt = (np.roll(flux,-1) - np.roll(flux,1))/(2*dx)

    return dhdt
```

I get the following error: `TypingError: non-precise type pyobject
[1] During: typing of argument at C:/Users/yhcha/method_of_lines/test_01_thinFilmEq.py (28)` I suspect it is due to `phiFun` and `tempFun`. They are functions which I supply at the time of calling. I make the functions arguments to the dhdt function just to keep things more general. When I try to remove `phiFun` and `tempFun` and explicitly give the function form inside `thinFilmEq`, the error goes away.

Then, I see the following error `TypingError: Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.roll' or unsupported use of the function.` I thought maybe `np.roll` is not supported although it is included in the official [website](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/developer/autogen_numpy_listing.html#numpy.roll). I tried to 'enlarge' the array to somehow manually apply the same thing as `np.roll` when dealing with the finite difference for periodic BC:

```
    def augment(x):
        x2 = np.empty(len(x)+2)
        x2[1:-1] = x
        x2[0] = x[-1]
        x2[-1] = x[0]
        return x2

    H = augment(x)
    hx = (H[2:]-[H:-2])/dx   # use this instead of hx=(roll(h,-1)-roll(h,1))/dx
```

My questions are:

1. It seems that I can get `numba` to work, at the expense of making the codes less generally (cannot supply an arbitrary function like `phiFun` and elegant (e.g. cannot use a one-liner with `np.roll`). Are there ways to get around it or is it just the price I need to pay when using `numba` to 'compile' the code?
2. The original version without `numba` is close to 10x slower than the Matlab version I coded, and the `numba` version is still around 3-4 times slower than Matlab. I don't really expect `scipy` to outperform Matlab, but are there other ways to speedup the code to bridge the gap?

Comment: Which Numba version do you use? `np.roll` may only be available in newer versions.

Comment: Are `phiFun` and `tempFun` themselves defined with `jit`?